# Use TPROXY feature of iptables with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04, iptables, proxy, routing

I'm trying to use the TPROXY feature of iptables.

For example :

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp -i eth0 -j TPROXY --on-port 5000 --tproxy-mark 1
```

This feature works perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04 (tested in a VM).

I would like to use this feature on a 22.04 ubuntu release. However, it doesn't seem to work. I have these errors :

```
unknown option "--on-port"
```

or

```
unknown option "--tproxy-mark"
```

The kernel modules required are there and set with a "m" value in the boot config. And I tried to enable these modules manually and it doesn't change anything...

```
modprobe nft_tproxy
modprobe nft_socket
modprobe nf_tproxy_ipv4
modprobe nf_tproxy_ipv6
```

If you have any leads, I'm interested!

Thanks !